# How to repeat or tile a texture in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I have a material

```
 <a-entity material="src:#imgGround; repeat: 400"></a-entity>
```

that I want to repeat or tile for the ground, but it is not working. How do I repeat or tile a texture in A-Frame?

I also want to do it for displacement and normal maps:

```
<a-entity id="ground_model" geometry="primitive:circle;radius:1" position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" scale="30 30 30" color="green" material="src:#imgGround;flatShading:false;transparent:false;repeat:44;normalMap:#imgGroundN;displacementMap:#imgGroundZ">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/material.html#built_in_materials_repeat

A repeat takes **two** values (for U and V mapping, or X and Y), not one.

```
<a-entity material="src:#imgGround; repeat: 20 20"></a-entity>
```

https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/material.html#built_in_materials_normaltexturerepeat

Similarly for displacement and normal maps, there are specific repeat properties:

```
<a-entity material="displacementMap:#imgGroundZ; displacementTextureRepeat: 4 4">
```